# Unable to set the path for chromedriver from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

In my program i am giving the below code to set the chrome driver path:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\usr\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
```

After running the program it throwing the error

> The driver executable does not exist: /home/ezetap0023/eclipse-workspace/EzeTap/\usr\lib\chromedriver.exe

Chromedriver is in usr\bin.

So what is the correct path I should give for setting path as [described in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3WqF.png)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Ubuntu, but chromedriver.exe is a windows version of chromedriver.
Get the correct one from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.35/ (latest one at the moment..)
Correct Linux chromedriver version will not have the .exe extension.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
The driver executable does not exist: /home/ezetap0023/eclipse-workspace/EzeTap/\usr\lib\chromedriver.exe
```

As you are on *Ubuntu* system you should mention the *absolute path* of the **chromedriver** in *Linux Style* stripping off the extension i.e. **.exe** part with respect to the exact location of the **chromedriver** as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/usr/lib/chromedriver");
```

Comment: hey its still showing  driver executable does not exist: /home/ezetap0023/eclipse-workspace/EzeTap/\usr\lib\chromedriver                                                       my chrome driver is in usr/lib ...why is it not detecting the path correctly

Comment: There was a typo, now it should work. Let me know the status.